# Instantiation of SharedViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvvm

i follow the coding in Flow tutorials. In one of them (communication between 2 fragments with shared ViewModel there is a depracated method ViewModelProviders.of(...:

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
     viewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
         @Override
         public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
             editText.setText(charSequence);
         }
     });
 }
```

The author explained that app knows when to destroy and recreate ViewModel so we shouldn't do it. I found a method which replaces the depracated ViewModelProviders:

```
//myNewMethod
viewModel= ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication()).create(SharedViewModel.class);
```

The problem is now, that this method create always a new instance of Shared ViewModel. So when i have two fragments, the method is called twice and generate two different shared ViewModels !

how to get rid of this and where should i instantiate the Shared ViewModel ? Main acitvity or still in fragment?

Comment: Problem solved. I should use ViewModel instead of AndroidViewModel And instantiate with :
` ViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);`

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I should use ViewModel instead of AndroidViewModel And instantiate with :

```
ViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
```